# Seven 2:1 rectangles covering a square

Tags: mathematics, geometry, tiling

Can you fully cover a square with 7 rectangles such that:

1. Every rectangle has 2:1 ratio, ie., length double its width.
2. No part of any rectangle is outside the square.
3. No two rectangles overlap.

Note that rectangles can have different size. This puzzle is from a Numberphile video (see link in comments) and is possibly well known, but I haven't seen it here.

Answer (score 9):

Is it possible?

> Yes

Why?

> 6x6 is the smallest possible area that can be divided into 7 possibly distinct X by 2X rectangles (36 = 18 + 8 + 5*2). And the following layout works:
>
> ```
>  AAAAAA
>  AAAAAA
>  AAAAAA
>  BBBBCC
>  BBBBDD
>  EEFFGG
> ```

> Perhaps the intent is that the rectangles must all be different sizes, which would make it less trivial to solve.

Comment: Correct and well done! Ok can you do it when all rectangles are different size?

Comment: Here is the cool Numberphile video about this puzzle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZ25tZ9z6uI

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky:  The video you link to explicitly allows matching sizes.  It starts with dividing a square into two $1 \times 2$ rectangles of the same size.

Comment: @Ross yes the original question allowed duplicate sizes. Now we are making it harder for fun :)

Answer (score 1):

By visual inspection of the diagram below it can be seen that a 3x3 square is divided into 7 rectangles whose sides are in 2:1 ratio.

[image: rectangles within square]